# Eslint configuration very slow

Tags: reactjs, eslint, config, lint

I'm facing an issue with my eslint configurations.
When i'm running `yarn eslint --cache -c .eslintrc.js './**/*' --ignore-path .eslintignore`, my terminal freeze for very long minutes.
Could you tell what a did wrong ? And if this configuration got somes problems ?

Thanks in advance

```
/** @type {import('@types/eslint').Linter.BaseConfig} */
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  globals: {
    chrome: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  plugins: ['react-hooks', '@typescript-eslint', 'react'],
  env: {
    webextensions: true,
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'airbnb-base',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/Tests/**/*.test.js'],
      plugins: ['jest', 'testing-library'],
      extends: [
        'plugin:jest/recommended',
        'plugin:jest/style',
        'plugin:testing-library/react',
        'plugin:testing-library/dom',
      ],
    },
    {
      files: ['src/**/*.{js,ts, tsx,jsx}', 'services/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'error',
      },
    },
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': 'error',
    'react/prop-types': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off',
    'no-nested-ternary': 'error',
    'no-restricted-globals': 'warn',
    camelcase: ['warn', { properties: 'never' }],
    eqeqeq: ['warn', 'always', { null: 'ignore' }],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'error',
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
    jest: {
      version: require('jest/package.json').version,
    },
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        project: [`${__dirname}/tsconfig.json`],
      },
      node: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        moduleDirectory: ['src/', 'services/', 'assets/', 'configs/'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Expected so enhancement in my eslint configuration, some tips to improve speed and maybe avoid duplication of rules